# Менять порядок элементов списка исходя из кратности входящего числа 5-ти

Tags: javascript, массивы

Предположим, у меня есть список дней недели:

```
let days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

И есть диапазон чисел от 1 до 1001.
Как написать код так, чтобы при каждом `number % 5 == 0` первый элемент списка попадал в конец.
В функцию при этом должно задаваться только число, диапазон от 1 до 1001 подразумевается уже внутри.
В итоге должно получиться следующее:

При `number == 5`:

```
let days = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
```

При `number == 10`:

```
let days = ['Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
```

и т.д.

Есть такое условие еще: однако из кратных 100 сдвигать лишь кратные 500, например, 700, 800, и 900 - не менять список, 1000 - менять.

Если нужна дополнительная информация, задавайте вопросы.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

console.log( bubu( 5) ); // [ "Tuesday", "Wednesday"...
console.log( bubu(10) ); // [ "Wednesday", "Thursday"...
console.log( bubu(15) ); // [ "Thursday", "Friday"...
console.log( bubu(35) ); // [ "Monday", "Tuesday"... (зациклилось)

function bubu(n) {
  if (n % 100 == 0 && n % 500 != 0) return days.slice(0);
  // Кратно 100, но не кратно 500 — не трогать массив (return прерывает функцию)

  let delta = (n / 5 | 0) % days.length;
  
  return [].concat( days.slice(delta), days.slice(0, delta) );
}
```

```css
code { white-space: nowrap !important; }
```

`let delta = (n / 5 | 0) % days.length;`

`n / 5 | 0` — равносильно `Math.trunc( n / 5 )`, а-ля целочисленное деление. Находит, сколько пятерок "поместится" в `n`. Скажем, для 100 → 20 штук.

Но зачем 20 раз кругами перекладывать элементы, если оно через каждые 7 штук встает на начальную позицию? `20 % 7` → 6 (остаток от деления 20 на 7), значит нужен сдвиг на 6 позиций. Можно разрезать массив на 6-й позиции и приклеить куски в обратном порядке.

---

* `return days.slice(0);` — `.slice(0)` создает новый массив из элементов days. Сделан так вместо `return days;` потому что не известно, что должны делать с полученным массивом. Будет не приятно, если его случайно пересортируют, перепишут элементы или еще что-то (см. «Мутация массива»).

Comment: Спасибо! Есть такое условие еще: однако из кратных 100 сдвигать лишь кратные 500, например, 700, 800, и 900 - не менять список,
1000 - менять. Как в этом случае?

Comment: @faceVB Бывает полезно в вопросе сразу написать условие целиком)) В этот раз изменение оказалось простым - добавил.

Comment: Спасибо! Думал сам разберусь)

Comment: Все равно перескакивает. Ввожу 98 и 101. Поидее не должен меняться, а меняется

Comment: @faceVB О_о Ну 98 и 101 оба не кратны 100, вот и меняются) Т.к. оно делит на 5 и отбрасывает дробную часть, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99 — все эти числа выдают одинаковый результат (как 95). Если ввести ровно 100, 200, 300 ..., 800, 900 — не меняет.

Comment: Да, а мне именно необходимо чтобы 95 поменяло, 100 не меняло (список остался таким как после 95), затем 105 и начало менять опять. Соответственно и для 200, 300 и т.д.

Comment: к тому же 100, 200 ... возвращают первоначальный список дней, где понедельник стоит первым.